# Going back to the previous activity in one click

Tags: android, android-activity, back, countdowntimer

I have 4 activities in my android app. 
In the first the user selects an option and goes to the next activity.
In the second the user selects an option and goes to the third activity.
The third contains a countdown timer which when finished goes to the fourth activity.

When I press back on activity 2 it goes to activity 1 as expected.
But when I press back on activity 3 (which has a countdown timer), the timer gets reset.
Only if I press back multiple times does it go back to the second activity. But even then, the fourth activity is displayed because of it's dependence on the timer. 
I want the third activity to go back to the second activity screen and finish the third activity so that the timer is stopped.

How should I proceed?

Comment: can you able to post the second and third activity entire codes.

Comment: Use a `CountDownTimer` and cancel it on `onBackPressed` in the third `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

In third activity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(waitTimer != null) {
       waitTimer.cancel();
       waitTimer.purge()
       waitTimer = null;
    }
    finish();
}
```

You don't require to start second Activity here because it is already in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

override `OnBackpressed` method and inside first stop the timer & finish activity , It works like what you need..(In 3rd activity)

Answer (score 0):

In third activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

timer.cancel
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
startAcctivity(intent);
finish();

}
```

Comment: It worked to the extent that it went to the previous activity, but the timer continued to run. So after the time got over it jumped to the second activity.

Comment: @user3431633 Can you please update with code fragments.